# Создание для функции выборки данных из Базы Данных(Java)

Tags: java, sql, функции, firebird

Здравствуйте, пишу программу, которая работает с БД, но возникла проблема с написание хорошей функции для выборке данных из БД, чтобы она могло хорошо работать как с запросами на выборку одно поля или нескольких, на выборку одного столбца или нескольких... Просто не хочется писать для каждого запроса отдельную ф-ию. Если кто-то еще добавит как для INSERT и UPDATE это реализовать, то будет вообще замечательно! Вот мой класс, в котором я хотел написать ф-ию:

```
public class FirebirdDB {

private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(FirebirdDB.class);
private static FirebirdDB firebirdDB = new FirebirdDB();

private Connection connection;
private Properties connectionInfo = new Properties();;
private PreparedStatement pstmt;
private Statement stmt;
private ResultSet result;

public boolean connect(){
    String urlDB = "jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost:C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\TestingSystem\\src\\main\\resources\\DB.FDB";
    connectionInfo.put("user", "SYSDBA");
    connectionInfo.put("password", "masterkey");
    connectionInfo.put("charSet", "Cp1251");

    try {
        Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FirebirdDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        connection = null;
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB, connectionInfo);
        if(connection == null) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}

public void disconnect(){
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Error of closing database.");
    }
}


public void execInsert(String query){
     ...
}

public ArrayList<String> execSelect(String query){
     ...
}


public static FirebirdDB getInstance() {
    return firebirdDB;
}


private FirebirdDB(){

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> на выборку одного столбца или нескольких

Берите все столбцы засовывайте в объект(Entity) и из него берите тот столбец который нужен.

> с запросами на выборку одно поля или нескольких

Кто и как будет решать сколько строк брать? По фильтру или по лимиту?

Не стоит очень сильно усложнять запрос к БД. Попытка сделать 1 запрос на 10-100 вариантов select, может сделать его сложным до невозможности и добавлять новый функционал будет очень сложно. Лучше на каждый уникальный запрос напишите отдельный запрос. Если запросы между собой похоже и их можно сгруппировать и при этом оставить код понятным - группируйте.

---

А вообще используйте какой-нибудь ORM

Comment: Я буду передавать текст запроса параметром и хотел возвращать результаты в удобном виде из ф-ии

Comment: @БалунВладимир тогда в чем ваша проблема? запрос вы передаете, а возвращаете  строки. Это конечно не очень хорошо, но решать вам

Comment: в каждой же таблицы разное кол-во столбцов и строк, соответсвенно их выбирать нужно по разному

Comment: @БалунВладимир так вы же запрос формируете на другой стороне, там тогда и задавайте все параметры. Модифицируйте ваш класс из вопроса, чтобы он возвращал коннект к БД. Создайте отдельный классы под каждую таблицу. В каждом из них по необходимости получайте соединение и делайте запрос к нужной таблице